# Computing Permutations with Partial Duplicates

Tags: permutations, co.combinatorics

I am looking for a way to compute the number of $K$ permutations of a multiset with $N*D$ elements where each group has exactly $D$ equal elements (and typically $D < N$ ).

I've got an application that actually generates these unique permutations and works on them, but I'd like to understand how I can compute the number of sets I'll have across various inputs without computing the entire result.

Example (in R):

```
N <- 19
K <- 4
# Implied D = 3 by just duplicating it in-place three times.

a <- append(1:N, append(1:N, 1:N))
b <- unique(gtools::permutations(length(a), K, a, set=FALSE))
```

`nrow(b)` in this case will be `130,302`.

This is slow and inelegant.  Can someone help me do this with actual math?

**Expanding a bit**

If `N` is 9 and `D` is 3, my input might look like this:

```
1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6 7 7 7 8 8 8 9 9 9
```

A standard permutation would look like this:

```
1    1    1    2
1    1    1    2
1    1    1    2
1    1    1    3
1    1    1    3
1    1    1    3
```

But at this point, I want to treat the things that look the same as the same, so I deduplicate to get the following:

```
1    1    1    2
1    1    1    3
1    1    1    4
1    1    1    5
1    1    1    6
1    1    1    7
```

The first (full permutation) provides 421,200 rows: $(9*3)! \over (9 * 3 - 4)!$

My final, deduplicated answer is `6,552` rows.  I'd like to know how I can get that without generating them all.

**New Discovery**

For my initial case where $D = K - 1$, I get the correct answer with $N^K - N$.

Comment: what's a "unique set of k "? could you make an example?

Comment: does this help?

Comment: It looks like you want to count ordered $k$-tuples from a set of size $n$ with at most $d$ repetitions of each element. 

Comment: The ordering part doesn't matter much to me (depending on what you meant by it).  I want AAAB and ZZZY and every permutation between except where that permutation is identical to another.

Comment: Do you want AAAB to be different from AABA or not?

Comment: You can see that people are answering different questions.  That's because you haven't defined your problem properly. Is the correct answer for N=19,D=3,K=4 130,302 or 6552?  What is the answer to Douglas' question just above this one?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use exponential generating functions.

For each of the N letters you could use the exponential generating function

$$ \sum_{i=0}^D \frac{x^i}{i!} $$

Cause each letter can be used at most D times this is the same for each letter.

Then for using all different letters the egf's have to be multipled (you have N different letters so N times):

$$ \left(\sum_{i=0}^D \frac{x^i}{i!}\right)^N $$

Then you are looking for the amount of different words of length K which is if you expand the expression above (which is possible if you put into it values for $D, N$. Then the coefficient of $x^K$ multiplied by $k!$ is your solution.

What I wasn't able to do right now is trying to expand the generating function into a series without using concrete values for $D$ and $N$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking the result should be:
n ^ k for d >= k
n ^ k - n ^ (k - d) for d < k

Comment: It's not deduplicated in the sense that the same *item* doesn't show up, but that the same sequence doesn't show up in the result.  i.e. AAAB, AAAC, but not another AAAB where the As were rearranged.

Comment: I don't know why I was making this far too hard. D will not matter, because no matter what it is, it will get deduplicated. Since what you're doing is (n*d)Pk with deduplication, your result is just n^k.

Comment: Okay, I missed the bit where you can only choose a number a maximum of D times.

If D is greater than or equal to K, number of rows = N^K
If D is less than K, number of rows should = N^K - N^(K-D)

Test that for me, see if the results make sense.

Comment: That's off in just a couple of cases:  http://pastebin.com/LUd8BMSR

Answer (score 0):

The number of $K$-permutations of the numtiset $\{ 1^D, 2^D, \ldots, N^D \}$ is
$$\sum_{j_1+j+2+\dots+j_N=K\atop 0 \leq j_i \leq D} \binom{K}{j_1,j_2,\dots,j_N}.$$
(summands here are multinomial coefficients)

Alternatively, denoting by $m_i$ the number of $j$'s equal $i$, we get a formula as the sum over restricted partitions:
$$\sum_{0m_0+1m_1 + \dots + Dm_D = K\atop m_0 + m_1 + \dots + m_D = N,\quad m_i\geq 0} \binom{N}{m_0,\dots,m_D} \frac{K!}{1!^{m_1} 2!^{m_2} \cdots D!^{m_D}}$$

For the example with $N=9$, $D=3$, $K=4$, the latter formula consists of four summands and gives:
$$\binom{9}{5,4} \frac{4!}{1!^4} + \binom{9}{6,2,1}\frac{4!}{1!^2 2!^1} + \binom{9}{7,1,1}\frac{4!}{1!^1 3!^1} + \binom{9}{7,2}\frac{4!}{2!^2}$$
$$ = 3024 + 3024 + 288 + 216 = 6552$$
as expected.